# Unexpected callTimes in async functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, sinon

I am testing with a react application with sinon, here is some backgrounds

- A file uploader is created for user to upload the file to server, after the upload has completed, a dialog box will pop out showing the details of the uploaded files

Container `<UpgradeApp />`

```
    class UpgradeApp extends Component {
    ...
    onFileUpload() {
      this.updateProgressBar(true); // I can only get this spy call detected
      return fetch(
               `/api/v1/upload-files/`,
               {
                   credentials: 'include',
                   method: 'POST',
                   body: formObj,
                   headers: {'X-CSRFToken': this.props.csrf},
               }
           )
          .then((res) => {
              if (res.status >= 400) {
                  // error handling here...
                  throw new Error(`Bad server responses, status code: ${res.status}`);
              }
              return res.json();
          })
          .then((ans) => {
            if (ans.success) {
                this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        dialog: {
                            ...this.state.dialog,
                            submitFn: () => {
                                return restfulApiCall(
                                    this.props.csrf,
                                    'upgrade',
                                ).then((res) => {
                                    if (res.status >= 400) {
                                        // error handling here...
                                        throw new Error(`Bad server responses, status code: ${res.status}`);
                                    }
                                }).catch((err) => {
                                    console.log('in catch');
                                    this.updateProgressBar(false); // Want to test whether this fn is called
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
          });
    }
    ...
}
```

Test `upgrade.spec.js`
The test is to check whether the function `this.updateProgressBar` is being executed, but I only get the called spyed in first call, but not the second one.

From the order of console log message, I can see `in catch` is before `in then`, so it is pretty sure that the catch block is being executed before the test case evaluating the function, is there any clues regarding on this? Thank you

```
...
const spyUpdateProgressBar = spy(upgradeAppInstance, 'updateProgressBar');

it('should hide the progress bar when upgrade is failed', function (done) {
        fetchMock.post(regUploadExp, mockOkUploadHttpResponse);
        fetchMock.post(regUpgradeExp, mockHttpUpgradeResponse);

        upgradeAppInstance.onFileUpload().then(() => {
            wrapper.update();
            expect(wrapper.find(ADialog).at(0).props().open).to.equal(true);
            const mockButtons2 = wrapper.find(ADialog).dive().at(0).find(Button);
            expect(spyUpdateProgressBar.calledOnce).to.equal(true); // This test is passed as expected
            spyUpdateProgressBar.resetHistory();

            // simulate upgrade process
            mockButtons2.at(1).simulate('click');
            console.log('in then');
        });

        setImmediate(() => {
            console.log(spyUpdateProgressBar.callCount);
            expect(spyUpdateProgressBar.calledOnce).to.equal(true); // failed in this expect, expecting true but get false
            done();
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're relying on a hack, this results in wrong behaviour. `setImmediate` - why is it there? Stick to promises. The quesiton doesn't mention testing framework. Is it Mocha? You don't need `done` there, it supports promises.

Comment: *catch block is being executed before the test case evaluating the function, is there any clues regarding on this* - it's unclear where submitFn is called, but the promise from it isn't chained anywhere, that's the clue. `restfulApiCall` should be mocked for starters, and `setState` likely, too. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the missing parts. I suppose `submitFn` should be extracted to separate method for testability reasons.

Comment: @estus thanks for the suggestions and sorry for the vague, I try to print out (using `console log`) in catch block (in source code) as well as the then block in test case (as shown in the code), and turns out the order is .catch in src run first, then .then in test case run next

Comment: it's unclear where `submitFn` is called > yes, that explains why I try to do a "hack" through `setImmediate`, because the `setState` pop up another dialog, and the `submitFn` is clicked by user to perform another action (actual upgrade), as I cannot control when the user clicks that dialogs button

Comment: So to conclude, the scenario is, user upload a file (async), then a dialog pops up, user the click ok and another async actions carried out

Comment: What you're doing is integration/e2e test. To be properly unit-tested, submitFn should be extracted to separate method. It should be stubbed in one test and directly called in another. This way a promise that it returns can be chained properly.

Comment: @estus Thanks for the reply, I put my bet on extracting the callback as a function and test it individually